# error fetching columns when using group by

Tags: r, group-by

I meant to create a 'ft' df with columns un, SM, FDtype, Species, ba, col, prodbol and n i am getting an error that says:  "Error in if_else(vol == 0, "XXX", SM) : object 'SM' not found" while the FAT table has SM and i checked the class it is character not a vector

```
ft <- FAT %>%
  group_by(un, SM, FDtype, Species, .add = FALSE) %>%
  summarize(ba = sum(ba), vol = sum(vol), prodvol = sum(prodvol), n = sum(nrep)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(across(c(ba, vol, prodvol), ~ . * 10)) %>%
  mutate(ba = if_else(vol == 0, 0, ba),
         SM = if_else(vol == 0, "XXX", SM))
```

I was expecting to get the ft dataframe as mentioned but alternatively following works but I wanted to use tidyverse instead of ddply:

```
ft <- ddply(FAT, c("un", "SM", "FDtype", "Species"), function(df)c(sum(df$ba), sum(df$vol), sum(df$prodvol), sum(df$nrep)))
ft[ ,c(5,6,7)] <- ft[ ,c(5,6,7)] * 10
colnames(ft) <- list("un", "SM","FDtype","Species", "ba", "vol", "prodvol", "n")
ft$ba[ft$vol==0] <- 0
ft$SM[ft$vol==0] <- "XXX"
```

Comment: After the call to `summarise`, all unused columns get dropped. So the `SM` variable is removed. When we cal `mutate(........ "XXX", SM), the SM is no longer available, that is why we get `object not found`.

Comment: The base R method is working because it is reintroducing the `SM` column name in the third line

Comment: We can only help so much without a proper reproducible example, which can be provided by sharing the data with `dput(FAT)`

Comment: If you add "SM" to your summarize() call, do you get the correct output? E.g. `  summarize(ba = sum(ba), vol = sum(vol), prodvol = sum(prodvol), n = sum(nrep), SM) %>%`

Comment: @GuedesBF - `SM` is a grouping variable, it would not be removed by the `summarise()` call.  As you say, OP needs to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it's going to be caused by OP having loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`.  OP - start a fresh session and load `dplyr` only.  If you need to use `plyr` functions as well, either call them via the namespace or load `plyr` before `dplyr`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I was testing both the old version and new ones before and now I tried reloading the script directly without loading `plyr` and it works fine. Thank you..